# Debian 11, Mastodon server, Ruby instalation problem, user mastodon

Tags: ruby, installation, debian, rbenv, mastodon

In the many manuals described process of [Mastodon instalation] (https://docs.joinmastodon.org/admin/install/), there are wrote:
"rbenv must be installed for a single Linux user, therefore, first we must create the user Mastodon will be running as:
adduser --disabled-login mastodon
We can then switch to the user:
su - mastodon"

Is it possible to log on "--disabled-login" account in Debian 11? I'm can not do it.

I try use command su - mastodon.
On other user account, system ask me password.
If I write password (user or root pasword) i can see:
"su: Authentication failure"
On root account I can see:
"This account is currently not available."

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem, you can use `sudo -u mastodon bash` instead.

Source: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/199029#issuecomment-1301964553